# What are the challenges ahead of bitcoin foundation?

Tags: bitcoin-foundation

What are the challenges ahead of bitcoin foundation? What are the issues they currently working on? How to track their activities?

Comment: bitcoinfoundation.org doesn't clearly explain what they do. Push bitcoin adoption, lobby banks and government authorities ??

Comment: I mostly doubt that they are getting paid to move slow, as this Bitcoin is not taking off, as I expected. I wish I should be wrong. They should be  more open, like publish roadmap, action items, call for help, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What are the issues they currently working on?

Perhaps I can help. I'm a member of the foundation; however, they haven't broadcast a specific mission or vision to us yet. That said, they are pursuing regulation and continued development of the Bitcoin protocol.

As for challenges, they face the following concerns:

1. Managing the growth of the ecosystem in a way that promotes mainstream adoption of bitcoin
2. Resolving issues with miscommunication and misinformation by the media and other entities
3. Working with businesses to better understand the regulatory and legal implications of bitcoin
4. Soliciting and integrating new developers and ideas into the protocol as the needs of the ecosystem mandate
5. Dealing with the consequences of government regulation on the ecosystem

There are far more issues to resolve; however, these to me seem to be the ones the foundation has invested the most work on.

> How to track their activities?

As of now, you can't outside highly public events such as the conference in San Jose. They are not a very transparent organization, which I suspect is a symptom of their age. Over time they will have to become better.

> What are the challenges ahead of bitcoin foundation?

For the moment, survival and relevance. They have yet to court the bitcoin community nor have a dynamic outreach program in the works to the best of my understanding. Longer term the issues of education and business adoption are also major challenges. As more people become aware of bitcoin, they will have a large list of questions and concerns. Depending on how they are addressed, the individual may have a positive or negative opinion of Bitcoin and will spread that opinion to their peers.

Answer (score 2):

The organization has many of your answers listed on it's website at bitcoinfoundation.org

https://bitcoinfoundation.org/about
Says the foundation's mission is to...
standardize bitcoin,
protect bitcoin,
and promote bitcoin

I would imagine that a good way to track their progress is by looking at...
https://bitcoinfoundation.org/blog/

Also, you can see a list of the foundations members at...
https://bitcoinfoundation.org/members

I'm sure if you were polite and had any questions that you may be able to contact a listed member with those inquiries.  :)